# How do I get started with phantomJS?

Tags: javascript, phantomjs

Been searching for a solution to printscreen or export my amCharts. I have never used phantomJS but looking into it, I think it will help me acheive my goals.

I am struggling to understand how to get started with it though, It downloads as an executable - would I run the executable as a link along with the function I would like i.e rasterize.js.

It is very new to me and I would appreciate the help.

Comment: what operating system are you using?

Comment: phantomjs is a headless browser meaning, it does things the way a browser does without showing you an actual browser. Through code you are allowed to navigate between pages, even edit them the way you edit using web inspector. You need to execute `/usr/local/bin/phantomjs rasterize.js` from backend server. For example in PHP by using `exec` method.

Comment: @nightgaunt I think the issue is actually executing phantomjs in a desktop environment using the commandline. That is why I want to clarify which operating system is used to add appropriate steps.

Comment: Artjom B. I am using windows 8.1

Answer (score 0):

You would just call `phantomjs.exe rasterize.js http://someurl.com yourlocalfile.pdf`.

You can also add options like papaerformat and zoom.

Take a look at the [quick start](http://phantomjs.org/quick-start.html) page

Comment: <button value="print chart" onClick="phantomjs.exe rasterize.js http://http://localhost/vpm_global/VPM-Global/index.html"  id="print2" width="200px">Print With RASTERISE.JS</button>

Comment: would I be able to use it in a button for instance

Comment: I meant command line, I don't think you would be able to do that... You should write a service you could call from your javascript that would run phantomjs on the server and somehow return or leave in a known place the resulting pdf.